# Is "Has As the Title" Correct Syntax?

Tags: word-order

While writing some information for an upcoming event I wrote this text:

"There will be a final presentation on [a date], which has as the title: [the title]"

When proof reading I was unsure if "has as the title" was correct. I did an exact string search on Google for the phrase and somehow had only 7 results, which is mad (only 2 of which were strictly my exact phrase)!

By the way I'm going to substitute in "is entitled" anyway but still wanted to know how right/wrong "has as the title" is.

Comment: This question has no research. Could you perhaps explain why you *don't* think it is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase:

> ... which has as the title: {title}

is at best awkward, but I would call it ungrammatical. That is because the use of the definite article "the" means "the title" should refer to some specific title that the reader already knows about, but here it doesn't.  A similar, but grammatical form would be:

> ... which has as its title: {title}

Also acceptable would be any of:

> - ... which is entitled {title}
> - ... which is titled {title}
> - ... called {title}
> - ... entitled {title}
> - ... known as {title}
> - ... the title of which is {title}